# How to get link inside li with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

My html:

```
<div id="myDiv">
        <ul class="myClass" style="display: block;">
            <li class="directory selected">
            <a href="#" rel="src/fd/">fd</a>
                <ul class="jqueryFileTree" style="display: block;">
                    <li class="file ext_jpg">
                    <a href="#">drevilblu.jpg</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I need to get `fd` by query:

```
var folderName = $("#myDiv").find("li.selected a").text();
```

But i receive `drevilblu.jpg` instead.
How to get `a` inside `li class="directory selected"`

Comment: If you look at it again, you'll notice that [you receive `fddrevilblu.jpg`](https://jsfiddle.net/hLb43583/) instead of `drevilblu.jpg`. You're selecting _both_ links, and `.text()` combines the inner text of the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following

```
var folderName = $("#myDiv").find("li.selected > a").text();
```

You need the first level child of li with class selected. For that you need `>`

Comment: Fine with "try", please provide an explanation why it does work, while OP's solution catches another link.

Comment: @nicael - Was on my way. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Use direct child selector instead:

```
var folderName = $("#myDiv").find("li.selected > a").text();
```

Comment: @nicael must have been submitted simultaneously. Otherwise I do check for answers before posting mine.

Comment: You have submitted yours almost a minute after another one was posted, enough to notice "1 new answer". I'd just delete it because it doesn't add anything to the post.

Comment: @nicael - Actually, no, the dynamic updates doesn't always happen within 30 seconds, and it's easy to miss another answer when you're typing, so imo this is no reason to downvote.

Comment: Anyway, glad to know that the OP has found an answer